# Create a button save for record on wizard - Odoov8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I've created a wizard with steps, of a model, in a custom module

Now, my problem is that in the 4th step, the workflow is finished, so I need to save all the fields filled, but I have no save button on my wizard

Is there a way I can do this by mantaining all the other fields of my wizard?

My wizard view:

```
<record id="view_wizard_prod_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">bsi.production.order.wizard</field>
        <field name="model">bsi.production.order</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Production Order">
              <field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="step1,step2,step3,step4" statusbar_colors='{"step3":"blue","step4":"blue"}' clickable="True" />
                  <group>
                    <group>
                      <field name="date_production" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step1')]}" />
                      <field name="product_id" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step1')]}" />
                      <field name="qty_available" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step1')]}" />
                      <field name="isbn1" attrs="{'invisible': [('type_prod', '!=', 'direct')]}" />
                      <field name="isbn2" attrs="{'invisible': [('type_prod', '!=', 'direct')]}"/>
                      <field name="isbn3" attrs="{'invisible': [('type_prod', '!=', 'direct')]}"/>
                      <field name="isbn4" attrs="{'invisible': [('type_prod', '!=', 'direct')]}"/>
                      <field name="isbn5" attrs="{'invisible': [('type_prod', '!=', 'direct')]}"/>
                      <field name="isbn6" attrs="{'invisible': [('type_prod', '!=', 'direct')]}"/>
                    </group>
                    <group>
                      <field name="type_prod" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step1')]}"/>
                      <field name="print_order2" attrs="{'invisible': [('type_prod', '!=', 'direct')]}" />
                      <field name="print_order2" attrs="{'invisible': [('type_prod', '!=', 'direct')]}"/>
                      <field name="print_order2" attrs="{'invisible': [('type_prod', '!=', 'direct')]}"/>
                      <field name="print_order2" attrs="{'invisible': [('type_prod', '!=', 'direct')]}"/>
                      <field name="print_order2" attrs="{'invisible': [('type_prod', '!=', 'direct')]}"/>
                      <field name="print_order2" attrs="{'invisible': [('type_prod', '!=', 'direct')]}"/>
                    </group>
                </group>
                <group>
                    <group string="Book Block" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}">
                            <field name="name_block" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                            <field name="category" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                            <field name="language" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                            <field name="edition" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                            <field name="size" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                            <field name="book_block_textp" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                            <field name="n_pages_one_color" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                            <field name="two_color" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                            <field name="four_color" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                            <field name="total" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                            <field name="text_print_code" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                            <field name="book_block_adpaper" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                            <field name="adnl_n_pages_one_color" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                            <field name="adnl_two_color" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                            <field name="adnl_third_color" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                            <field name="adnl_four_color" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                            <field name="adnl_total" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                            <field name="adnl_text_print_code" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                            <field name="book_block_txtep" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                            <field name="n_of_end_pages" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                    </group>
                    <group string="Book Size" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}">
                            <field name="name_size" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                            <field name="description_size" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                            <field name="forme_size" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                            <field name="plate_size" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                    </group>
                </group>
                <group>
                    <group string="Book Edition" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}">
                            <field name="name_edition" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                    </group>
                    <group string="Book Binding" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}">
                            <field name="name_binding" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                    </group>
                    <group string="Cut Off" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}">
                            <field name="name_cut" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                            <field name="description_cut" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                            <field name="cutoff_size" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                    </group>
                    <group string="Paper Master" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}">
                            <field name="name_papermaster" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                            <field name="description_papermaster" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                            <field name="paper_type" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                            <field name="uom_papermaster" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                            <field name="gsm_papermaster" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                            <field name="std_cost_rate" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                            <field name="qty_in_kgs" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                            <field name="size_width" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                            <field name="size_height" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                    </group>
                </group>
                <group>
                    <group string="End Paper" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}">
                            <field name="name_end_paper" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                            <field name="category_end_paper" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                            <field name="size_end_paper" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                    </group>
                    <group string="Printing Code" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}">
                            <field name="description_code" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                            <field name="size_code" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                    </group>
                    <group string="Book Edge" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}">
                            <field name="name_book_edge" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                    </group>
                    <group string="Job Rate" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}">
                            <field name="name_jobrate" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                            <field name="binding" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                            <field name="size_binding_job_rate" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                            <field name="bind_variety" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                            <field name="rates" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                            <field name="addl_rate" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                            <field name="uptoforme" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                    </group>
                </group>
        </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

I just need it to be clickable and save the data on the table.
I saw some solution like this one:

```
<button string="Save" name="create" type="object"/>
```

But it doesn't works, so, any ideas?

**EDIT**

This is my defined method:

```
@api.multi
def save_data(self, vals):
    # and here you use you wizard fields 
    self.name
    self.date_production
    self.type_prod
    self.product_id
    self.qty_available
    self.isbn1
    self.isbn2
    self.isbn3
    self.isbn4
    self.isbn5
    self.isbn6
    self.isbn7
    self.isbn8
    #print_order = fields.One2many('bsi.print.order', 'production_orders', string="Print Order", copy=True)
    self.print_order2
    self.name_block
    self.category
    #self.other_fields
    return (bsi_production_order, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
```

But it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 546, in _handle_exception
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 583, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 319, in _call_function
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 316, in checked_call
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 812, in __call__
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 412, in response_wrap
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 944, in call_kw
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
TypeError: create() takes exactly 2 arguments (5 given)
```

Comment: Have you defined the `create` method in the Python side of your `bsi.production.order` model? What do you mean by it doesn't work? Any errors?

Comment: Hi, No, not really, there was an answer somewhere stating that this approach (just the button) could work, but a create method it's what I actually need, but I'm not really sure if it'll need to call super() or if it could be simpler... kind of confused on it

Comment: I think you can keep it pretty basic provided you pass in the `vals` you need. The `create` method will basically just return `super(your_model, self).create(vals)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a button to a footer and show it when you hit last step.

```
         <button string="Save" name="save_data" type="object"/>
```

And in your wizard define a function to save

```
       @api.multi
        def save_data(self):
                # and here you use you wizard fields 
                 self.some_field
```

Comment: Hi, Thank You, I've added the fields, and in the end I wrote ´return (bsi_production_order, self).create(vals)´ but it says ´TypeError: create() takes exactly 2 arguments (5 given)´ Any ideas?

Comment: Did you define a create method in your model

Comment: Edited my question, Thank You